# How to get the number of active threads started by specific class?

Tags: python, multithreading, count

code looks like below:

```
class workers1(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
        # ...do some stuff 

class workers2(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
       # ...do some stuff 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # start workers

while True: 
    print "Number of threads active", threading.activeCount()
    print "Number of worker1 threads", ?????, "Number of worker2 threads", ?????
```

Is there a way to get the number of threads being active by originating class ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is a minor modification of Doug Hellman's [multiprocessing ActivePool example code](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/multiprocessing/index.html) (to use threading). The idea is to have your workers register themselves in a pool, unregister themselves when they finish, using a threading.Lock to coordinate modification of the pool's active list:

```
import threading
import time
import random

class ActivePool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ActivePool, self).__init__()
        self.active=[]
        self.lock=threading.Lock()
    def makeActive(self, name):
        with self.lock:
            self.active.append(name)
    def makeInactive(self, name):
        with self.lock:
            self.active.remove(name)
    def numActive(self):
        with self.lock:
            return len(self.active)
    def __str__(self):
        with self.lock:
            return str(self.active)
def worker(pool):
    name=threading.current_thread().name
    pool.makeActive(name)
    print 'Now running: %s' % str(pool)
    time.sleep(random.randint(1,3))
    pool.makeInactive(name)

if __name__=='__main__':
    poolA=ActivePool()
    poolB=ActivePool()    
    jobs=[]
    for i in range(5):
        jobs.append(
            threading.Thread(target=worker, name='A{0}'.format(i),
                             args=(poolA,)))
        jobs.append(
            threading.Thread(target=worker, name='B{0}'.format(i),
                             args=(poolB,)))
    for j in jobs:
        j.daemon=True
        j.start()
    while threading.activeCount()>1:
        for j in jobs:
            j.join(1)
            print 'A-threads active: {0}, B-threads active: {1}'.format(
                poolA.numActive(),poolB.numActive())
```

yields

```
Now running: ['A0']
Now running: ['B0']
Now running: ['A0', 'A1']
Now running: ['B0', 'B1']
 Now running: ['A0', 'A1', 'A2']
 Now running: ['B0', 'B1', 'B2']
Now running: ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3']
Now running: ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3']
Now running: ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4']
Now running: ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4']
A-threads active: 4, B-threads active: 5
A-threads active: 2, B-threads active: 5
A-threads active: 0, B-threads active: 3
A-threads active: 0, B-threads active: 3
A-threads active: 0, B-threads active: 3
A-threads active: 0, B-threads active: 3
A-threads active: 0, B-threads active: 3
A-threads active: 0, B-threads active: 0
A-threads active: 0, B-threads active: 0
A-threads active: 0, B-threads active: 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a semaphore for each class and get their counts: see [link](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#semaphore-objects).

Comment: **Links die.** Please avoid referencing links as the entirety of your answer. Anything is preferable – including copy-pasting the contents of that link for historical preservation if you absolutely must.