# How to check the number of currently running threads in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python - how to get the numebr of active threads started by specific class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046986/python-how-to-get-the-numebr-of-active-threads-started-by-specific-class)

I'm new in python, i want to get count of running threads at any time...is there any built in support for this or i have to maintain it manually (e.g. count veriable...) ?

Answer (score 99):

[threading.active_count()](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.active_count) seems to be what you're looking for :

> Return the number of Thread objects currently alive

Comment: great stuff, thank you.  print('number of current threads is ', threading.active_count())

Comment: threading.activeCount() returns the same as it is an alias for the mentioned function.

Comment: @therealak12 not in snake_case