# recursive function calls and queuing in python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, iteration, conditional-statements

I have the sketch of my code as follows:

```
def func1(c):
    return a,b

def func2(c,x):
    if condition:
        a,b = func1(c)
        x.append(a,b)
        func2(a,x)
        func2(b,x)
    return x

x = []
y = func2(c, x)
```

The problem, as you might have figured out from the code, is that I would like `func2(b)` to be computed in parallel with `func2(a)` whenever condition is true i.e. before `b` is replace by `a` new `b` from `func2(a)`. But according to my algorithm, this clearly can not happen due to the new b's.

I do think such a problem might be perfect for parallel computing approach. But, I did not use it before and my knowledge about that is quite limited. I did try the suggestion from  [How to do parallel programming in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20548628/how-to-do-parallel-programming-in-python), though. But I got the same result like the sketch above.

Comment: Parallelizing this looks difficult because you don't want to spawn new threads for *every* recursive call -- if the recursion is deep you'd use tons of threads (way more than # CPUs) and none would be fast.  Also I'm confused when you say "b is replaced by a new b".  Each stack frame (recursive call) gets it's own `b` in the `a, b =` statement -- whereas the `x` list is the same globally, so all recursive calls will append to the same `x`.

Comment: I see. Yeah, what I meant by new `b` is the following: when condition is true `a_0,b_0 = func1(c)`, then `func2(a_0,x)` if condition is again true, `a1,b1 = func1(a_0)` .... It's after completing this that it goes to `func2(b,x)`. Therefore the only chance it has is to compute only `func2(b_k,x)` where `b_k` is the last `b` by `func2(a,x)`. But, I would like every `func2(b,x)` to be computed for each `b`'s i.e. `b_0, ..., b_{k-1}`. I am not sure if I explained the issue well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caveat: Threading might not be parallel enough for you (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html note on the `Global Interpreter Lock`) so you might have to use the `multiprocessing` library instead (https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).

...So I've cheated/been-lazy & used a thread/process neutral term "job".  You'll need to pick either threading or multiprocessing for everywhere that I use "job".

```
def func1(c):
    return a,b

def func2(c,x):
    if condition:
        a,b = func1(c)
        x.append(a,b)
        a_job = None
        if (number_active_jobs() >= NUM_CPUS):
            # do a and b sequentially
            func2(a, x)
        else:
            a_job = fork_job(func2, a, x)
        func2(b,x)
        if a_job is not None:
            join(a_job)

x = []
func2(c, x)
# all results are now in x (don't need y)
```

...that will be best if you need a,b pairs to finish together for some reason.
If you're willing to let the scheduler go nuts, you could "job" them all & then `join` at the end:

```
def func1(c):
    return a,b

def func2(c,x):
    if condition:
        a,b = func1(c)
        x.append(a,b)
        if (number_active_jobs() >= NUM_CPUS):
            # do a and b sequentially
            func2(a, x)
        else:
            all_jobs.append(fork_job(func2, a, x))
        # TODO: the same job-or-sequential for func2(b,x)

all_jobs = []
x = []
func2(c, x)
for j in all_jobs:
    join(j)
# all results are now in x (don't need y)
```

The NUM_CPUS check could be done with `threading.activeCount()` instead of a full blown worker threa pool ([python - how to get the numebr of active threads started by specific class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046986/python-how-to-get-the-numebr-of-active-threads-started-by-specific-class)).

But with multiprocessing you'd have more work to do with  `JoinableQueue` and a fixed size `Pool` of workers

Comment: Thanks for detailed algos and options. Following your opinion to use multiprocessing (`import multiprocessing as mlt`), I am not able to translate the 'job'-attached variables. 1. How could I find number_active_jobs() in mlt? or are you suggesting me to use thread as well? 2.  What did you mean by `a_job=None`? if it is a variable, when is it updated for the last condition to make sense? 3. I also am too inexperienced in this 'mlt' module to understand `fork_job(func2, a, x)`. I checked `mlt.forking.` but didn't know which one you were referring to.

Comment: NOTE: in order for x to be shared memory across the multiprocessing processes, `x` would need to be a `mlt.Array` instead of a simple Python list.  Answers:  
(1) After a bit more digging it looks like a fixed size pool would be easier than trying to count the forked jobs:  `pool = mlt.Pool(processes=4)`
(2) Ooops. I edit the code above to add the assignment that I forgot.
(3) the equivalent of fork_job(func2, a, x) with a multiprocessing Pool would be something like `pool.apply_async(func2, [a, x])
(*) Lots more detail in the examples https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: Hey Douglas. Thanks a lot. My fear was in fact pointless. The code by itself does the job as I wanted, just fine. But definitely, your feedback are great input for me cus my next step is just using multiple cores for which I need 'mlt' or 'th' that I have no enough knowledge of. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation I have a feeling that it is not that `b` gets updated (which is not, as DouglasDD explained), but `x`. To let both recursive calls to work on a same `x`, you need to take some sort of a snapshot of `x`. The simplest way is to pass an index of a newly appended tuple, along the lines of

```
def func2(c, x, length):
    ...
    x.append(a, b)
    func2(a, x, length + 1)
    func2(b, x, length + 1)
```

Comment: thanks, but DouglasDD understood my problem. Quite rankly, I also thought there might be a simple trick by some identifier to switch parameters for func2, similar to your opinion. I am not sure, though, if yours would work for me. Because a,b = func1(c) i.e. there is another function func1 to be called within func2.