# spark-submit continues to hang after job completion

Tags: python, hadoop, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to test spark 1.6 with hdfs in AWS. I am using the wordcount python example available in the examples folder. I submit the job with spark-submit, the job completes successfully and its prints the results on the console as well. The web-UI also says its completed. However the spark-submit never terminates. I have verified that the context is stopped in the word count example code as well.

What could be wrong ?

This is what I see on the console.

```
6-05-24 14:58:04,749 INFO  [Thread-3] handler.ContextHandler (ContextHandler.java:doStop(843)) - stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage,null}
2016-05-24 14:58:04,749 INFO  [Thread-3] handler.ContextHandler (ContextHandler.java:doStop(843)) - stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/json,null}
2016-05-24 14:58:04,749 INFO  [Thread-3] handler.ContextHandler (ContextHandler.java:doStop(843)) - stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages,null}
2016-05-24 14:58:04,749 INFO  [Thread-3] handler.ContextHandler (ContextHandler.java:doStop(843)) - stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/job/json,null}
2016-05-24 14:58:04,750 INFO  [Thread-3] handler.ContextHandler (ContextHandler.java:doStop(843)) - stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/job,null}
2016-05-24 14:58:04,750 INFO  [Thread-3] handler.ContextHandler (ContextHandler.java:doStop(843)) - stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/json,null}
2016-05-24 14:58:04,750 INFO  [Thread-3] handler.ContextHandler (ContextHandler.java:doStop(843)) - stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs,null}
2016-05-24 14:58:04,802 INFO  [Thread-3] ui.SparkUI (Logging.scala:logInfo(58)) - Stopped Spark web UI at http://172.30.2.239:4040
2016-05-24 14:58:04,805 INFO  [Thread-3] cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend (Logging.scala:logInfo(58)) - Shutting down all executors
2016-05-24 14:58:04,805 INFO  [dispatcher-event-loop-2] cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend (Logging.scala:logInfo(58)) - Asking each executor to shut down
2016-05-24 14:58:04,814 INFO  [dispatcher-event-loop-5] spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint (Logging.scala:logInfo(58)) - MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
2016-05-24 14:58:04,818 INFO  [Thread-3] storage.MemoryStore (Logging.scala:logInfo(58)) - MemoryStore cleared
2016-05-24 14:58:04,818 INFO  [Thread-3] storage.BlockManager (Logging.scala:logInfo(58)) - BlockManager stopped
2016-05-24 14:58:04,820 INFO  [Thread-3] storage.BlockManagerMaster (Logging.scala:logInfo(58)) - BlockManagerMaster stopped
2016-05-24 14:58:04,821 INFO  [dispatcher-event-loop-3] scheduler.OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint (Logging.scala:logInfo(58)) - OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
2016-05-24 14:58:04,824 INFO  [Thread-3] spark.SparkContext (Logging.scala:logInfo(58)) - Successfully stopped SparkContext
2016-05-24 14:58:04,827 INFO  [sparkDriverActorSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator (Slf4jLogger.scala:apply$mcV$sp(74)) - Shutting down remote daemon.
2016-05-24 14:58:04,828 INFO  [sparkDriverActorSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator (Slf4jLogger.scala:apply$mcV$sp(74)) - Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
2016-05-24 14:58:04,843 INFO  [sparkDriverActorSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator (Slf4jLogger.scala:apply$mcV$sp(74)) - Remoting shut down.
```

I have to do a ctrl-c to terminate the spark-submit process. This is really a weird problem and I have no idea how to fix this. Please let me know if there are any logs I should be looking at, or doing things differently here.

Here is the pastebin link of the jstack output of spark-submit process: 
http://pastebin.com/Nfnt4XmT

Comment: I do not know python but I would go for checking for which thread is active even when Spark context is shutdown.
Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046986/python-how-to-get-the-numebr-of-active-threads-started-by-specific-class

Comment: You might have to stop the spark context at the end of the application by doing `sc.stop()`

Comment: I already stop the spark context. This is post that.

Comment: What are you using for the "master"?  "spark-submit --master ???"

Comment: I tried both master=yarn-cluster and local

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with custom thread pool in my spark job code. I found out that **spark-submit** hangs with using custom **non** daemonic thread pools in your code.
You could check [`ThreadUtils.newDaemonCachedThreadPool()`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/ThreadUtils.scala) to understand how spark developers create thread pools or you could use this utils but be careful as they are package private.

Answer (score -1):

For me:
On local it stops but keeps sending logs when executed on Cluster. I think it is expected behaviour.
Got this from another answer and worked for me.

```
val sc=new SparkContext(conf)
try{
      //code goes here
}
finally{
      sc.stop()
}
```

This technique worked both in Spark and PySpark.
[sample shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afXVu.png)